# breeze inlinecount missing when ordering by related property

Tags: breeze

I'm using breeze to sort results of my queries and also do paging/counts. I noticed that when I use orderBy with a property that is part of the entity it works fine (ex. orderBy('description')). However, when I use a related property with orderBy the inline count is null (ex. orderBy('vendor.name')). Looking at the responses I see:

With a native property:

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"Breeze.WebApi.QueryResult, Breeze.WebApi","Results":[lots of stuff],"InlineCount":63}
```

With a related property:

```
[lots of stuff]
```

It returns just the results portion, which still seems to work, but the inline count ends up as null. My requests all look something like this:

```
$filter: [bunch of stuff]
$orderby:Vendor/Name desc (or Description desc)
$top:25
$expand:PreviousItem
$inlinecount:allpages
```

Can anyone else reproduce, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated 8/13/2013**

As of Breeze v 1.4.1 available now, this has been fixed.

---

We were able to reproduce the problem and it appears to be a bug. 
We are working on a fix.